# Printing List in TKinter using for loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to print each items in list as TKinter label using a for loop when I click a button. Below is the code I have, however it doesn't output anything.

The result I am looking for is in first instance the label should print "111111" and in next instance "222222".

```
from tkinter import *
def get_searchid():

    search_id = ["1111111",'222222']

    for search in search_id:

        l1 = Label(root, text=search)
        l1.pack

root = Tk()

button1 = Button(root, text="Search Me", command=get_searchid)
button1.place(x=50, y=50)
button1.pack

root.mainloop()
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve this or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You have to call it. `l1.pack()`

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks for pointing this out, clearly missed that. Works as desired!